# Is validation set necessary when fine-tuning a model using synthetic images?

Tags: validation, computer-vision, training-data, fine-tuning

- update

Can I split the small test set into a validation set **realB-v** and a test set **realB-t**, then I fine-tune the model and test on the test set **realB-v**. Then, I swap the validation set and the test set and train a new model. Can I report the average results on two trainings?

- original post

I have a pre-trained model **M** trained on the real dataset **realA**, I test it on another real dataset **realB** and get very poor results because **realA** and **realB** have domain gaps. Since real images in **realB** are difficult to acquire, I decide to generate synthetic images like **realB** and use these images **syntheticA** to fine-tune the model **M**.

I wonder if I still need to get a validation set? If so, the validation set should be splitted from **syntheticA** or **realB**? **realB** is already a very small set (300 images).

In my view, I don't think a validation set in this case is necessary. If I directly fine-tune the model and get hyperparameters according to the accuracy rate on **realB**, it won't cause generalization problems because the images I use for fine-tuning are all synthetic.

I'd like to hear your views. Thank you.

Comment: I don’t know, but I do know that if you tune your model **M** until it gives good results on **realB**, then **realB** is part of your training, and you need to find a different, independent validation set to know the true accuracy of your model.

Comment: @CrisLuengo If I split the training set **SyntheticA** into a training set and a validation set, does that make sense? Since the validation set is synthetic, even if there is a high accuracy on the verification set, it doesn't mean anything when I test on **realB**.

Comment: selecting a subset from training it correct.   synthetic or not.  ideally your validation set validates that the training data has been sufficiently generalized and can be interpolated successfully by the network.